# How to do a rotation animation loop with easing?

Tags: animation, node-editor

What I have right now is an NLA track that has it's repeat set to 7 to loop an animation. This animation rotates an object from 0 to 360 degrees. (See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/493/20394)

I turned off easing by turning linear extrapolation on.
I just noted the above details for clarity so you know what I have now. (I am more than willing to try a different method when suggested)

What the problem is now is that the animation stops immediatly when the repeat is over, and also starts immediatly at constant speed. What's the best way to both loop a rotation animation AND ease the animation in and out? Thanks!

Comment: If you set repeat in the NLA then it will repeat a set number of times. Setting [linear extrapolation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42039/935) in the graph editor will give an endless rotation. Check that you set the extrapolation on the rotating axis and not another value. If you want to [share your blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) someone might see what you missed.