# I'm having trouble with image rotation

Tags: texturing, camera, import, image, video

I'm trying to import an image into Blender that I can make rotate continuously. It's just a simple 2D circular image that I want to make rotate. For an example of what I'm trying to do, see the last 15-20 seconds of one of the more recent videos here. (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQiojTHkAvFvdCSajklqUXA) His logo is a T shaped and rotates horizontally, mine would be a circular image, and rotating against the background rather than on the axis his is. For anyone wondering, I'm working on creating an outro card for my YouTube videos. Any help?

I've fiddled with Blender some, but not enough to have any real skill at it. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: u mean this logo https://yt3.ggpht.com/-WbIiig9DqiI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/bcGpzmOvOek/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg

Comment: @atek yeah. That's his logo, but the one I've got is circular in nature. I'm wanting it to be against the background and rotating (I'm thinking) counter clockwise, rather than on the axis his rotates on. My problem is I only know how to import images onto a plane.

Comment: watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ub2a3kSfrw4) u will get ur answer

Comment: @atek I can already do that. I'm looking to bring them in as an object that I can rotate.

Comment: @Crash Underride you should learn animation basics then: you shoould start with the blender manual  (try https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/keyframes/introduction.html) and then learn about graph editor extrapolation https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html. There are other related questions too: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42001/how-can-i-properly-rotate-my-object

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the add image as plane addon to import your image as a texture on a plane, if your image is transparent around your logo then you can use that to only make you logo visible.
2. Animate the rotation of the plane. In the 3D viewport press <kbd>I</kbd> and choose rotation.
3. In the graph editor select the axis you want to rotate and add a [generator modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/fmodifiers.html#generator). Play the animation and adjust the values until you get a rotation speed you want. Negative numbers will reverse the rotation.

[image: flat spin example]

To get a more detailed object spinning or if you need to cut out the image surrounding your logo, you will need to do a little modeling. Starting with a circle, you can either extrude it or use a solidify modifier to add thickness. UV unwrap it and add the image to the material, you can use the material created by add image as plane if you started with that.

[image: spinning with thickness]