# rotation in only a single axis

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

i have a plane and it is rotated in the x axis and i want to rotate the object in y axis 90 while keeping the x axis rotation as previous but when ever i am rotating the plane in the y axis it is also changing the x axis rotation and if i apply the transforms then the animation is not working correctly
[image] [image]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42039/935) help? - the second part.

Answer (score 1):

so to be clear what are you trying to make?

first when u create a plane
[image: first when u create a plane]

this is x rotate 53 degree
[image: this is x rotate 53 degree]
rotate 90 degree
[image: rotate 90 degree]

Comment: yeah i did this and i just want to change the orientation of the plane from landscape to portrait while keeping the rotation on the x axis

Comment: its something like the animation from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahpUb_RzGJA at 1:00

Comment: never mind i have figured out

Comment: @PrateevBardhan Please write an answer to your own question explaining what you did - to help anyone else who might be having a similar problem. You can then ‘accept’ the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed xyz euler coordinate system with quaternion and used local transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Get into edit mode and select the plane and press Shift-Numpad-7. View will orient exactly in front of plane. The you can rotate. Now you can rotate it in Y-axis without affecting X-Axis rotation.