# Looping Animation

Tags: animation, camera

I have animated the camera in order to make a seamless animation. But I'm confused if there's a slight jump when the camera loops again. Can I upload my file so some can please take a look at it, if I have missed something?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42001/how-can-i-properly-rotate-my-object  Keyframes are "eased" by default, giving a curve look to graph, slowing the gradient at keyframe points.  Making linear extrapolation is possibly what is required.

Comment: Hi batFINGER I have already set my interpolation to linear in the preference.

Comment: You need to set the same keyframe as the start frame not to the end frame, but to the end_frame + 1 else the 2 last frames repeat

Comment: Here is a screen shot of my timeline

https://imgur.com/Fmn2euK

Also the camera location starts at Y-10m and finishes at Y 10m, the camera is perfectly snapping at start and end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gorgious has commented, it sounds like an off-by-one error?

For a quick, even,  50-frame loop of a rotation, for example, without going into the Graph Editor and using features like [Extrapolation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html#extrapolation) or [Cycling](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#cycles), you could:

- Set a key at frame 1 of 0 degrees
- Set a key at frame **51** of 360 or -360 degrees, depending on the desired direction of rotation
- In the timeline,<kbd>T</kbd> set all selected keys to 'Linear' interpolation.
- Set the Playback Range to 50.

To tidy up, you could insert a keyframe at frame 50 of the existing rotation at that point, and delete the key at frame 51.

Comment: Hi Robin.

I see where you're coming from. I was use to Animating objects in After Effects, and there is no skipping frame like you implied in Blender, which worked like a gem. Seems a bit weird that the seamless animation has to be like this in order not to jitter a frame, but in the end it's the result which matters.

Thank you.

https://imgur.com/R1HO21k

Comment: @blenderbreath   hehe... doesn't seem weird to me .. you just don't want the frame at 50(=0) to be repeated at frame 51(=1)